# How to filter in excel between two time intervals (not dates)

Tags: excel, time, filter

I have report in Excel containg incident tickets and their creation time. My task is to filter them based based on whether they are in BH, OOH or Weekends. Starting BH are from 7 AM to 7 PM, OOH are from 7 PM to 7 AM.

Data is located in cell B, and formated as "3/1/2018  12:27:37 AM "
Cell B is formated as Date, not text.

My goal is to perform this WITHOUT changing the overal structure of the report, (without helper column), but instead to use "between" filter or some other date filter.

Searching the web i found many solutions with helper column, advanced filter, using MOD or Hour, but i am unable to implement them to work.All i keep getting is blank output

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated

**Sample Image of the table**
[image: Sample Image of the table] - 25k+ rows formated like this starting from 1st Mar 2018, ending at ending at 31st of May 2018

**Desired Output**
[image: Desired Output] - Goal is to present chart showing how many tickets are logged in BH, OOH, and Weekends, in a similar way.

Sample table : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FSy_XWfpInWRXKK8Y_Qx032NpZav7k5e/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Clossest thing i found is referenced here https://superuser.com/questions/1386053/filter-time-range , yet it includes helper column, which i aim to avoid

Comment: Show your input and intended output, because there may be several methods possible. just to note, techniques involving dates will also work - just need to change the functions to hour ? min and not day/date...

Comment: I have added snapshots , hope this clarify my question

Comment: You should be able to use the **Advanced Filter**.  BTW, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for testing a solution. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter the data is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, thank you for the advice Ron, I have uploaded sample table in Google Drive. I am obviously a noob and any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up the advanced filter, insert some rows at the top of your graph, and then enter your formulas for the various conditions.

For example, for the OOH filter (edited to be consistent with the counting formula):

[image]

I have inserted enough rows so that the first row of your data is Row 8, and `B8` is the first timestamp.

I have also assumed that you want to exclude weekends for the OOH filter.

Given this as a basis, you can construct other filter criteria ranges for your other requirements.

Note that the "Header" in row 1 is merely for convenience and can be blank.  When using formula critera, a requirement is that this header **NOT** be the same as any column header.

But, if your goal is to just get a graph of the number of entries for the different time statuses, you could just use a formula.

I converted your data to a **Table** so as not to worry about range references. I find that extraordinarily helpful, both in understanding the formula, and also in creating dynamic range references which will adjust automatically as data is added or deleted from a table.

```
BH:       =SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(Table1[Opened])>=7)*(HOUR(Table1[Opened])<=19)*(WEEKDAY(Table1[Opened],2)<6))
OOH:      =SUMPRODUCT(((HOUR(Table1[Opened])>19)+(HOUR(Table1[Opened])<7))*(WEEKDAY(Table1[Opened],2)<6))
Weekend:  =SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(Table1[Opened],2)>=6))
```

Or, with regular addressing:

[image]

Comment: you mister are a lifesaver. Thank you for your explanatory answer, you really helped me grasp the concept. Furthermore thank you for your guidance how to post questions so that i can get promt answers from professionals like yourself. You rock !

Comment: Unfortunatelly filtering does not work as intended. I have implemented your solution and even though the formulas count correctly, advanced filter does not work and can`t list the entries properly. For example OOH tickets are shown as 1262 while formula is showing them at 519. i have uploaded file for you to check with the above solution, any guidance will be much appreciated https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xfYvrL_gmjHM90fGjnxHP262kct_9kkZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @N.Nonov The difference is caused by both inconsistent logic between the formula and the criteria (my fault -- edited to correct; examine the comparison operators to understand) as well as your excluding Row 1 from the criteria range.  The first row of the criteria range is the column label, not the first formula.

Comment: I have made corections based on your answer. Some problems still persirst, i have uploaded corected workbook at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14Sr1dxImvP5SKfwGZkiJGJHZXN2Mhn7RZ4Uy_W657es/edit?usp=sharing.  Main problem i can`t properly list tickets in BH, please check sheet BH, there are some higlighted entries that ilustrate the issue Second problem is the difference count between OOH produced by formula and by advanced filtering (519 vs 367), which one is credible ? Weekend tickets match by filter and by formula (both 239)

Comment: For BH i tried the following sets of combinations, with each of them being inacurate****B2=HOUR(B8)>7 / B3=HOUR(B8)<19****
 
 ****B2=HOUR(B8)>=7
 B3=HOUR(B8)<19****
 
**** B2=HOUR(B8)>7
 B3=HOUR(B8)<=19 ****
 
 ****B2=HOUR(B8)>=7
 B3=HOUR(B8)<=19****
 
 ****B2=HOUR(B8)<19
 B3=HOUR(B8)>7 ****
 
 
 ****B2=HOUR(B8)<=19
 B3=HOUR(B8)>7****
 
 ****B2=HOUR(B8)<=19
 B3=HOUR(B8)>=7****
 
 ****B2=HOUR(B8)<19
 B3=HOUR(B8)>=7****
 
**** B2=HOUR(B8)<19
 B3=HOUR(B8)>7****

Comment: @N.Nonov  I have no issues with setting filters; copying the visible cells to the particular worksheets, and then comparing the counts by formula and by filtered rows.  I get results of `239`, `519`, and `25513` for Weekend, OOH and BH respectively.  And that is how many rows get filtered.  I can't tell what you are doing wrong on your latest worksheet, as it is only available for viewing.  Probably you are using incorrect criteria or incorrect criteria ranges.  To get `367` for OOH you are still **incorrectly** defining your criteria range as I mentioned above.

Comment: Would you mind providing me with BH values you are usin?, i understand that this is looking like i want you to do the job for me, but i am strugling with all types of scenarios and can`t get what i am doing wrong. For OOH i did it exactly as the edited answer. Uploaded sheet with 367 result and editable worksheet for reference https://drive.google.com/file/d/15R_IQHqEzgLT7AQHzcOKISgN8_dcJ7jZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @N.Nonov won't be able to look at your sheet until this evening. With regard to OOH, I believe you are still not including label row from the criteria range (B1). With regard to BH, since the criteria are `and`'d, you need to have them in the same row. See help for advance filtering for further explanation.

Comment: I  finaly managed to get data properly. BIG THANKS Ron Rosenfeld, your guidance was priceless ! for the portion what i did wrong it was as you corectly assumed that i did not include the "criteria label" and messing with the "and" statements. Once again i must say, you sir ROCK !